# Is there a good phrase for an "alternating effect" of X on Y?

Tags: phrase-requests

X has a positive effect on Y under one condition (let's say for younger people under the age of 30) but X has a negative effect on Y under different condition (e.g. for everyone else).

Comment: A word useful in the description of the situation might be *Counterintuitive*.

Comment: *Differing* is a possible word. Because different groups of people, or plants, or whatever, are affected differently does not mean the difference is paradoxical or even unexpected.

Comment: It will be rare that such a precise relationship obtains.

Answer (score 1):

**divergent effects**

> **divergent**
> Moving or extending in different directions from a common point: diverging from each other
>
> *divergent paths* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/divergent)

---

> Ketamine injection, however, in Group A had a significant **reduction** in SPO<sub>2</sub> whilst those in group B had a significant **rise** in SpO<sub>2</sub>. Further **divergent effects** were observed with pulmonary blood flow
> **increasing** in children with mild cyanosis (group B) and **reducing** in those with moderate to severe cyanosis (group A). [*Side Effects of Drugs Annual 39*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Side_Effects_of_Drugs_Annual/AOjWDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22divergent%20effects%22&pg=PA118&printsec=frontcover)
>
> A large study provides causal evidence of the **opposing effects** of
> plasma low-density lipoprotein (LDL) levels on ischemic and
> hemorrhagic stroke in a Chinese population and suggests there is a a
> net benefit associated with LDL lowering. [N. Parikh and M. Elkind;
> ***Divergent effects** of lipids on stroke*](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41591-019-0413-7)

> The chief finding of the present study is that serotonin exerts
> **divergent effects** on the coronary circulation of patients with coronary atherosclerotic lesions and those with normal coronary
> arteries. Indeed, several in vitro and in vivo studies have
> demonstrated that **serotonin can both dilate and constrict the
> coronary vessels** of various species, its net effect being related to
> the presence or absence of a normal endothelium. [***Divergent
> Effects** of Serotonin on Coronary-Artery Dimensions and Blood Flow
> in Patients with Coronary Atherosclerosis and Control Patients* in
> *NEJM*, March, 1991](https://www.nejm.org/journal-articles?query=recirc_mostViewed_railB_article)
>
> The idea that there might be two types of adrenergic receptors in the
> same type of cell, mediating **divergent effects** depending on which
> type of receptor predominated, was decidedly unappealing to some
> investigators. [G. A. Robison et al.; "The Catecholamines" in G.
> Litwack (ed.) *Biochemical Actions of Hormones Vol. 2*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Biochemical_Actions_of_Hormones_V2/s9YGKhmhfaMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22divergent%20effects%22&pg=PA84&printsec=frontcover)
>
> The 'same' geopolitical phenomena generated significantly different
> outcomes in different societies, because these arrangements varied,
> just as **Japanese colonialism took different forms and had different
> consequences** in Korea and Taiwan.
>
> The **divergent effects** of different state socialist legacies are
> especially marked when comparing enterprises in countries that were
> integrated into the Council for Mutual Economic Assistance (CMEA), on
> the one hand, with those in the former Yugoslavia, on the other.
> [Richard Whitley; *Divergent Capitalisms*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Divergent_Capitalisms/F5raI82z-kQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22divergent%20effects%22&pg=PA209&printsec=frontcover)

> The authors were unable to provide a simple explanation for the
> **divergent effects** of sodium fluoride on subcutaneous sarcomas and lung
> tumors induced by benzopyrene. [National Research Council; *Health
> Effects of Ingested Fluoride*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Health_Effects_of_Ingested_Fluoride/CMQd6nkX86EC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22divergent%20effects%22&pg=PT131&printsec=frontcover)

> The **divergent properties** of CBGA suggest that it may be useful
> against [generalized tonic–clonic seizure] but perhaps contraindicated
> against focal seizures. [L Anderson et al,; *Cannabigerolic acid, a
> major biosynthetic precursor molecule in cannabis, exhibits
> **divergent effects** on seizures in mouse models of epilepsy*](https://bpspubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/bph.15661)

Comment: Yes, this seems well attested.

Answer (score 0):

A name for an effect of a drug or treatment that is opposite the usual one is a *paradoxical reaction* or *paradoxical effect*. [See Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoxical_reaction)

If there's no "usual effect", you could call the two opposite effects *paradoxical effects.*